# In app purchases not works on iOS 7 return error 'Invalid product identifier: (null)'

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I test IAP on 6.1 emulator all ok but if switch to ios7 it return error when cal buy method

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception
 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid product identifier:
 (null)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 7 simulator disables In App Purchase Sandbox mode. Use a device.

Comment: same here was working fine suddenly iOS 7 I get 'invalidProductIdentifiers'. When checked with iTC it's not invalid and intact correct. Any solutions ?

Comment: Ok I fixed my issue. Now it turned out I commented out a line of code that had an NSArray that I stored the SKProductsRespone.productucts.  Also I had to accept new payments contract in iTC.